# How to pass application/user data to the ChannelHandler Netty

Tags: java, netty

When you design an a client that is going to connect to a lot of servers, like a crawler.

You will code something like that :

```
// the pipeline
public class CrawlerPipelineFactory  implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        return Channels.pipeline(new CrawlerHandler());
    }
}

// the channel handler
public class CrawlerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}


// the main :
public static void main(){
    ChannelFactory factory = new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    ClientBootstrap scannerBootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(factory);
    scannerBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new CrawlerPipelineFactory());

    while(true){
        MyURL url = stack.pop();
        ChannelFuture connect = scannerBootstrap.connect(url.getSocketAddress()); 
    }
}
```

Now when you are in your ApplicationHandler, the stuff that implements your SimpleChannelHandler or WhatEverStreamHandler, (CrawlerHander in the example) the only piece of information you get is the socketAdress you are connecting to that you can recover in "public void channelConnected()" function.

Ok but what if I want to recover some user data, like the MyURL object you see in my code example ?

I use a dirty hack, I use a Map<"ip:port",MyURL> so I can retrieve the associated data in channelConnected because I know ip:port i'm connected on.

This hack is really dirty, it won't work if you are connecting simultaneously to the same server (or you'll have to bind to a local port and use a key like "localport:ip:remoteport" but it's so dirty).

So I'm seeking what is the good way to pass data the the CrawlerHander ?

It would be cool if we could pass this data via the connect() method of the bootstrap. I know I can pass argument in my ChannelPipelineFactory.getPipeline() because it's invoked via connect(). But now we can't, so here is another dirty hack I use :

EDIT:

```
// the main
while(!targets.isEmpty()){
    client.connect("localhost",111); // we will never connect to localhost, it's a hack
}

// the pipleline
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    return Channels.pipeline(
        new CrawlerHandler(targets.pop()) // I specify each new host to connect here
    );
}

// in my channel handler
// Now I have the data I want in the constructor, so I m sure I get them before everything is called
public class CrawlerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
    ExtraParameter target;
    public CrawlerHandler(ExtraParameter target) {
        this.target =  target;

// but, and it's the most dirty part, I have to abort the connection to localhost, and reinit a new connection to the real target
    boolean bFirstConnect=true;
    @Override
    public void connectRequested(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        if(bFirstConnect){
            bFirstConnect = false;
            ctx.getChannel().connect(target.getSocketAddr());
        }
```

Comment: What are the synchronization issues you are talking about ? Pass it to the ChannelPipelineFactory is the way to go atm. I think we had the idea before to be able to pass some kind of attachment in the connect method which would then get passed automaticly to the ChannelPipeline.getPipeline() method. But I was not able to find the email about it atm.

Comment: Hey Norman, you are on the good way, all my problem would be solved if I could pass attachment in connect() so I could pass it to the consuctor of my ChannelHandler() via my ChannelPipelineFactory.getPipeline(Object theNewExtraParamater);

Comment: Sorry about my last sentences it was not a sync issue, it's because my another method is to dirty, look at the edited post, I added a code example

Comment: and just read the answer of Jestan Nirojan if you want to see a sync problem example.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to Channel via Bootstrap.

[Netty.io 4.1](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/bootstrap/AbstractBootstrap.html#attr-io.netty.util.AttributeKey-T-) & [SO - Adding an attribute to a Channel before creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845884/adding-an-attribute-to-a-channel-before-creation)

Update to this answer while very late.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data to the newly connected channel/channel handler using ChannelLocal or  in ChannelHandlerContext (or in the Channel it self in latest Netty 3.x) using a connect future listener. In below example, ChannelLocal is used.

```
public class ChannelDataHolder {
  public final static ChannelLocal<String> CHANNEL_URL = new ChannelLocal<String>(true);
}

  // for each url in bootstrap

  MyURL url = ....; 
  ChannelFuture cf = scannerBootstrap.connect(url.getSocketAddress());

  final String urlString = url.getUrl();

  cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                ChannelDataHolder.CHANNEL_URL.set(future.getChannel(), urlString);
            }
   });



  //In the handler

 public class CrawlerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
   @Override
   public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
      String urlString = ChannelDataHolder.CHANNEL_URL.get(ctx.getChannel()); 
      // ...use the data here
   }
 }
```

Note: instead of ChannelLocal, you can set and get the data using

- ChannelHandlerContext.setAttachment()/getAttachment()
- Channel.setAttachment()/getAttachment() in latest 3.x version of Netty

but both approaches does not support type safety.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a good solution, in your code example you can't be sure that the cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() will be called before the connection is made, if the connection is made immediately after connect(), the channedConnected function will be called before your cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {" line

Comment: You are wrong :), in practice that is not possible , channel future listeners always executed before firing the respective event by the NioWorker thread. for example connect future listener will executed before the channelConnected() in the handler.

Comment: Sorry dude, YOU are wrong. I'm not talking about the channelFutureListenner, I totally agree with you it will be called before the associated event. BUT : the problem is the way you call addListenner, you call addListenner after the connect() How can you be sure that the connection would not be already made before addListener ? You can't.

Comment: You can even use the same listener to call bootstrap.connect() in case of connection failure to reconnect.

Comment: Your solution could work if {connect(); addListenner();} was in a critical/atomic section so we could be sure that nothing else is executed between them. But it's not the case and it's like a hack, it's a bit dirty.

Comment: Your argument is not correct. bootstrap.connect() operation is asynchronous, and that's why we have future listener in Netty (You can check the future listener documentation for more details). I can explain how it works: bootstrap.connect() will return immediately (after few milli secs), that gives you enough time to add your listener before connect complete (which is a I/O operation takes more time). I have used this pattern in many projects and it worked all the time. It may looks like dirty solution but you can safely rely on Netty's thread model for the order of execution of future listene

Comment: @user1344303, Since you have the connect future after calling bootstrap.connect(), you should call addListenner() immediately, That is obvious.

Comment: LOL "that gives you enough time to add your listener before connect complete". 
Sorry but we will never agree on this topic. For me there is a HUGE problem of synchronization in your example, even if it works 99% of the time for you, 
it won't if you handle severals thousand connections in // and have a lot of I/O and your CPU on high load. A lot of thing could happen between connect() and addListenner() due to threads/proccess context switching and I/O.
It's a trivial sync problem, you can't rely on the speed of execution between 2 statements, add a critical section and it's OK.

Comment: @p1erz, Netty also uses ChannelFutureListener heavily, have a look at org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener usage in Netty source (for example org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http.HttpTunnelingClientSocketChannel  .connectReal() method implementation), So you are saying that HttpTunnelingClientSocketChannel/Netty is broken :).  BTW I have contributed to Netty too. I wish, someone else from the Netty Team could explain this bit more.