# Adding an attribute to a Channel before creation

Tags: java, netty

I'm looking for a way to add an attribute to a `Channel` before creating it.

The reason is that I need to associate the `Channel` to some arbitrary object so that I have the ability to get the object from the channel (e.g. in the `channelActive()` method where I have the `Channel` and I need the associated object).

The `Bootstrap` exposes an attr() method but an attribute that would be added this way is available to all channels created from this `Bootstrap` instance.

Also, adding the attribute after Channel creation is problematic since the `channelActive()` method may be called before the attribute is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who needs it, here is a solution:

```
ChannelFuture registerFuture;
try {
    registerFuture = castBootstrap.register().await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Handle the exception
}

final Channel channel = registerFuture.channel();
channel.attr(MY_ATTR_KEY).set(/* some value */);

ChannelFuture connectFuture = channel.connect(/* Resolved socket address */);
```

Instead of relying on the `Bootstrap` to create the `Channel`, the code above creates and registers the `Channel`, and connects using the `Channel` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Adding via `Bootstrap.attr(...)` will make the attribute available in `channelActive(...)` as the attribute is set before `fireChannelActive()` is called.

If you do not want to use this method you can also just add a `ChannelInboundHandler` that overrides `channelRegistered(...)` and add the attribute there by yourself.

Comment: Regarding the Bootstrap method, the attribute will be available for all channels created with the Bootstrap, correct? I need an attribute per channel (the key will be the same for all channels but not the value).

Comment: channelRegistered() also presents the same issue. The only argument I receive is the context (which also includes the channel) and I don't know at this stage what the value of the attribute is.

Comment: why you can not "inject" the value of the attribute into the Channelinboundhandler ?

Comment: The ChannelInboundHandler is singleton (Spring @Component) as it maintains state shared by all channels.